# Configuring custom pop-up window in ArcGIS Online using field hyperlinks?

Tags: arcgis-online, popup, html

I'm working on configuring a custom pop-up window in ArcGIS Online and have been using the "Create Link" feature to add hyperlinks to the pop-up window. I've been adding hyperlinks based on the name of the field in the dataset that contains a URL (e.g. {URL}).

In instances where there is no hyperlink associated with a given field (i.e. the field is empty), I've been finding that the pop-up window sometimes displays this small blue line that if clicked, will direct to a blank page. In other instances where there is no hyperlink associated with a given field, the blue line doesn't appear. In an ideal world, I wouldn't want the link to appear at all so that it is evident that there is no data to be displayed.

Does anyone know how to remove the line?

[image]

Comment: Just a quick thought, but you sure that one of the fields you are using might contain some whitespace?  That might be what is causing the inconsistency.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! However, I looked into that and none of the fields have whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this happens because there's a space in your data. Go back to content, choose the layer you're working with, then go to the data tab, and see if there are any data entries with a space. Yes, silly but that has been the case for me.